# aws - can I use EC2 without S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Why and when exactly should I use EC2 with S3?

I'm using EC2 to install tools like Gitlab and Rundeck. It works fine without S3 storage.

The problem is just if I terminate instances, I'll lose my files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: Yes, you can use EC2 without S3. S3 is cloud storage and isn't used for EC2 images.

S3 is used for storing files, such as distributions, backups, and can even be used for static websites.

To answer the second part of your question: when creating storage for a new EC2 instance, uncheck the **Delete on Termination**, so it will be saved if you ever choose to terminate the EC2 instance.

[image]

Be careful though, I've had problems in the past where AWS will not let you reuse volumes that were used with a marketplace image.

Answer (score 2):

EC2 uses EBS, not S3, for storing the volumes. (In fact, I don't exactly know how to make it use anything besides EBS. S3 is used for AMIs, which are basically templates that are copied to EBS when creating an instance.)

**Option 1:** Don't terminate your instances. Note that terminate means delete, not stop. You can stop them without terminating them.

**Option 2:** Configure your EBS volumes to not be deleted on termination. The volume will be detached rather than deleted. You can then attach it to another machine later.

You can also attach multiple EBS volumes to an instance, so if you want to save your data only but discard the OS, simply place your data on a secondary volume. The primary volume can be deleted and the secondary volume can be preserved. Delete-on-termination can be configured per-volume.